# GDB doesn't save log

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I put in  `~/.gdbinit`

```
set logging on 
set logging file /mnt/gdb_log.txt
```

But gdb doesn't save log to this file

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that ?

Because `set logging file` will only take effect *next* time you `set logging on`.

The order of the two statements matters; you should reverse the two lines you have.
As-is, the logging *is* happening, but to `$CWD/gdb.txt` file, not the one you specified.